# How can I parse a string of "AND"s and "OR"s into a usable conditional statement?

Tags: c#, parsing, conditional-statements

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to provide certain functionality required for a business application I'm working on.

Basically, we have a string in the DB that contains a conditional statement such as

`"(("SomeString.Contains("XYZ") AND SomeString.Contains("VBN")) OR SomeString.Contains("ABC"))"`

*(This string could contain tons of conditional statements, this is just a simple example).*

What I am asked to do is pull that string in from the DB and insert it into an If statement to determine whether or not "SomeString" meets those requirements. "SomeString" will just be a specific string that I will replace once the code is run.

The end result in my mind would be as follows...

```
if (((SomeString.Contains("XYZ") && SomeString.Contains("VBN")) || SomeString.Contains("ABC")) {
    return true;
}
```

The problem lies in the fact that even if I parse the "AND"s and "OR"s into their code form of "&&"s and "||"s, the value entered into the if statment is still of type string which means the statement will not be treated as a conditional statement.

Is there any way to do this in C#? Libraries or otherwise.

I'm not necessarily looking for someone to write the code for me, I just need a push in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Are the partial statements always `string.Contains()`?

Comment: This is called an "expression evaluator".

Comment: @D M - Yes always string.Contains()

@Ben Voigt - Do expression evaluators work with .Contains()? I was under the impression that those were only for mathematical evaluations.

Comment: @Dalan: An expression evaluator is what makes your debugger's "Watch" window work...  It is all a tradeoff between complexity and capability.